# Accelerating Postgres Group By

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to accelerate a query of the form:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT c0."insert_date" as t, count(*) FROM "clicks" AS c0 WHERE (c0."link_id" = 29) GROUP BY t ORDER BY t;

 Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=57016.09..57021.29 rows=208 width=12) (actual time=2068.781..2069.062 rows=183 loops=1)
   Group Key: insert_date
   ->  Sort  (cost=57016.09..57017.13 rows=416 width=12) (actual time=2068.776..2068.840 rows=549 loops=1)
         Sort Key: insert_date
         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 50kB
         ->  Gather  (cost=56954.32..56998.00 rows=416 width=12) (actual time=2068.310..2178.702 rows=549 loops=1)
               Workers Planned: 2
               Workers Launched: 2
               ->  Partial HashAggregate  (cost=55954.32..55956.40 rows=208 width=12) (actual time=2061.287..2061.353 rows=183 loops=3)
                     Group Key: insert_date
                     ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on clicks c0  (cost=3939.03..55707.38 rows=49388 width=4) (actual time=148.147..2039.441 rows=40061 loops=3)
                           Recheck Cond: (link_id = 29)
                           Heap Blocks: exact=9508
                           ->  Bitmap Index Scan on clicks_link_id_index  (cost=0.00..3909.40 rows=118530 width=0) (actual time=145.150..145.150 rows=120182 loops=1)
                                 Index Cond: (link_id = 29)
 Planning time: 0.223 ms
 Execution time: 2180.492 ms
(17 rows)
```

It's particularly slow when the number of indistinct (number of clicks per day) is very high.

Any suggestions on how to speed this up? (I don't really know anything about indexes, although I'm happy to learn if pointed in the right direction).

Comment: Do you have defined any indices? A quick guess would be that an index over `link_id, insert_date` would speed this up a lot.

Comment: @Bergi so this query can do an index-only scan?  note to the OP, this will only really speed up queries exactly like this, if you reference any other fields from `clicks` then you quickly hit cases where this optimisation wouldn't be applicable

Comment: Normally there are a couple of extra WHERE params, it's hard to know exactly what they'll be ahead of time.

Comment: what sort of drive is the data stored on?  I'm struggling to differentiate between a spinning disk (and relatively few seeks) and a slower SSD (with lots of unpredictable reads).  huh, or maybe the box is busy servicing other queries?

Comment: In production, it's on a Google Cloud Postgres instance (although the above test is on my SSD laptop).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a couple of background points:

- [statistics](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/planner-stats.html) look good, i.e. it's guessing roughly how many rows it'll get back and seems to be propagating this information correctly.  this is important because lots of times the query planner does the "wrong thing" because it doesn't have a very good idea of the data in the table
- 1.8 seconds (i.e. ~90% of the time) is spent executing `Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on clicks`, this is fetching the actual data from the table that the index scan identified as relevant

while executing this query PG is therefore likely spending most of its time doing IO, and only a small amount amount of time processing the data.  the aim would therefore be to either make it read the data more efficiently or just to read less data

- creating an index specifically for this query, as suggested by @Bergi,  would allow PG not to read the data from the table but this will only tend to optimise a few specific queries, see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-index-only-scans.html for the official docs
- random access is much slower than sequential, so you could try rearranging the table to optimise for this query, e.g. see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-cluster.html but this comes with lots of caveats and probably won't help you long term (but is sometimes useful!)
- normalising your table so rows don't take as much storage space can help, but if rows are still randomly scattered throughout the table then this isn't going to help much
- a faster IO subsystem, especially something that can do faster random IO, will help everything, but will obviously cost more on an ongoing basis
- cache results, if you're doing this a lot you can save the results into a different table (or "materialised view") and use that rather than going to the source data all the time

basically what's "best" depends on quite a few things, I'd suggest searching for a few of the terms I've used and reading about them if you're new to this sort of stuff